# how to search sign like <>{}!#@$ on search engine?

Tags: python, search

I wander how "n << 1 == n*2 and n >> 1 == n/2" work,but I can't get answer with search engine.

Comment: What language is this in? They look like bit shifts to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The honest answer is you need some *apriori* knowledge of what the `<<` and `>>` operators are called to effectively search using Google.

A contrived answer is to Google search for something like `python "<<" ">>" operator`. The quotation marks in the Google search term guarantees that the quoted strings show up in each hit.

The first link is to ["9.9 operator -- Standard operators as functions"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html). If you search that page for `'<<'` you eventually find

```
Left Shift      a << b  lshift(a, b)
Right Shift     a >> b  rshift(a, b)
```

Which leads you (by searching for `lshift`) to the definition (on the same page):

```
operator.lshift(a, b)
operator.__lshift__(a, b)

    Return a shifted left by b.
```

This too might not be so clear, however. It means that the binary representation of `a` is bit-shifted to the left `b` places and the resultant value is returned. (`>>`, the rshift operator works the same way, except that the bit-shifting is done to the right.)

Answer (score 1):

They look like bit shifts to me. At least in C++, 'n>>1' means shift all the bits (1's and 0's) to the right. That is decimal 6 (binary representation 110) becomes 11 (shifted the 0 off) which is decimal 3. That is, if n=6, then n>>1==n/2 would evaluate to true.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift for more info and a better explanation.